# Add a lightning component to a related list on a record page layout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, related-list, action, list-button

I currently have an object called related files that has 8 different object lookups and I have created a button for it that uses javascript to extract the record ID so just 1 button can be used for all the 8 objects on the related files related list. I am now looking to replace this to upgrade to lightning and have been unable to find a solution.

I have created a lightning component but I cannot see how I would add this to a related list on a record page layout. I can create an action but this can only be added to the records highlights panel which is not useful as the button is relevant to the related list rather than the record.

I have also looked at using just a standard URL button but I would need to create 8 different buttons for all 8 objects or else create a long formula field to pass the various objects record ID's e.g. IF(NOT(ISBLANK(object1.id)),object1.id, IF(NOT(ISBLANK(object2.id).... etc.

I would really appreciate any thoughts or advice on how to best solve or deal with this problem.